# Convert hex-string to string using binascii

Tags: python

By hex-string, it is a regular string except every two characters represents some byte, which is mapped to some ASCII char.

So for example the string

```
abc
```

Would be represented as

```
979899
```

I am looking at the [binascii](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html) module but don't really know how to take the hex-string and turn it back into the ascii string.
Which method can I use?

Note: I am starting with `979899` and want to convert it back to `abc`

Comment: The number does not consist of hex numbers but base 10 ints

Comment: oh, yes you're right. Should be `616263` === `abc` since they represent hex bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the string back from the hexadecimal number you can use

```
s=str(616263)
print "".join([chr(int(s[x:x+2], 16)) for x in range(0,len(s),2)])
```

See http://ideone.com/dupgs

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ord()` to get the integer value of each character:

```
>>> map(ord, 'abc')
[97, 98, 99]
>>> ''.join(map(lambda c: str(ord(c)), 'asd'))
'979899'
>>> ''.join((str(ord(c)) for c in 'abc'))
'979899'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need binascii to get the integer representation of a character in a string, all you need is the built in function `ord()`.

```
s = 'abc'
print(''.join(map(lambda x:str(ord(x)),s)))  # outputs "979899"
```